# Connect using a specific port to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, database-connection, port

How do I connect to SQL Server using a port configured in IPALL-->TCP Dynamic Ports ? What will be the connection string in my MVC application ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not appropriate to use Dynamic port in connectionstring because it will get changed on sql services restart, You can use server name (or IP Address) instead. If you decide to use Port Number than change it to (Data Source=IPAddress:PortNumber).

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="Data Source=<Database server Name>\<Instance Name (if any)>;
                          Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;
                          Integrated Security=False;
                          User ID=MyUserID;Password=MyPassword;
                          MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```